# Have heard that + past perfect or simple past?

Tags: tense, phrase-choice

If I want to say “I heard that many people died in this place in the past” with the “have heard” tense, which one of those two below is the correct one?

1. I have heard that many people died in this apartment.
2. I have heard that many people had died in this apartment.

Answer (score 0):

The **first** is correct:

*I have heard that many people died in this apartment.*

Informally we might say, *I've heard many people died in this apartment*.

The **second** uses the past perfect. It is well explained [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/past-perfect). And you can test yourself.

Comment: Saying, *I **have** heard that many people **have** died in this apartment,* would work just as well and be idiomatic.  It's *have* and *had* that don't work together.

Comment: Yes, your sentence works fine, but "have died" is not what the OP asked about. And I think we CAN say, "_I **have** heard that many people **had** died in this apartment by the time the ambulance arrived._"

Comment: I'm not sure we can say that. *I heard that many people **had** died before the ambulance...*, works and *I **have** heard that many people died before the ambulance....* works but *I **have** heard that many **had**...* doesn't work. Your past perfect is clashing with your present perfect.  Drop one and everything works.

Comment: Hmm. This needs more thought than I have time for at the moment. Or maybe more than I'm capable of! We'll see after Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct.

The second is incorrect because past perfect represents a time that is more past relative to some simple past time, "the past of the past", but there is no simple past time in that sentence for the past perfect to be more past than.